# javascript function not firing onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery

given this html snippet

```
 <div id="imageSelection" class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PostedFiles,"Select images/videos" ,new {id="fileSelect",@for="fileElem", @class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-success", style="width:144px;" })
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PostedFiles, new
      {
       type = "file",
       id = "fileElem",
       @class = "col-md-10 form-control",
       style="display:none;",
       multiple = "multiple",
       accept = "image/*", 
       onchange = "handleFiles(this.files)"

     })                  
</div>
```

which works fine, you click the button, the file picker opens, you select some files and click the button to close the file picker. The onchange event is not firing (onchange is the event suggested by the example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Using_a_label_element_to_trigger_a_hidden_file_input_element))

It generates this html in the page

```
<div id="imageSelection" class="form-group">
     <label class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-success" for="fileElem" id="fileSelect" style="width:144px;">Select images/videos</label>
     <input accept="image/*" class="col-md-10 form-control" id="fileElem" multiple="multiple" name="PostedFiles" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)" style="display:none;" type="file" value="" />

</div>
```

Here is the script

```
 <script>
$(document)
    .ready(function () {
        //element variables for the thumbnail display
        var dropbox = $("#dropbox"),
            filePropertyDisplay = $("#loadingImageFileProperties"),
            fileName = $("#dd_filename"),
            fileSize = $("#dd_filesize"),
            fileType = $("#dd_filetype"),
            gallery = $("#imageGallery"),
            uploading = $("#imageUploading"),
            fileSelect = document.getElementById("fileSelect"), //$("#fileSelect"),
            fileElem = document.getElementById("fileElem"), //$("#fileElem"),
            messages = $("#messageArea");

        gallery.hide();
        uploading.hide();

        //add event listeners to handle events
        dropbox.on("dragenter", function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        dropbox.on("dragover", function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        dropbox.on("drop", function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();

            var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
            var files = dt.files;

            handleFiles(files);
        });

        fileSelect.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            if (fileElem) {
                fileElem.click();
            }
            e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigation to "#"
        }, false);

        //fileSelect.on("click", function (e) {
        //    if (fileElem) {
        //        fileElem.click();
        //    }
        //    // prevent navigation to "#"
        //    e.preventDefault(); 
        //});

        function handleFiles(files) {
            alert(files.length);
        }

    });
</script>
```

I originally was trying to stick with JQuery but couldn't get that to work with .on() either, so i reverted back to Javascript, per the example, but that doesn't work either.

The drop functionality works, and calls handleFiles but the fileElem onchange method doesn't fire.

Comment: Are you sure that the generated markup contains the `onchange="handleFiles(this.files)"` attribute?

Comment: @ninetwozero... yes it does

Comment: You need to define `handleFiles()` *outside* of the document.ready handler. Putting it inside means it's out of scope of the `onchange` event attribute. Better yet, get rid of your outdated `on*` attributes completely and use unobtrusive JS/jQuery to bind your events instead

Comment: @Rory McCrossan... handleFiles, where it is, is working fine from the "drop" event. and you are correct, it now works with it defined outside doc ready. Not sure what you mean by "Better yet, get rid of your outdated on* attributes completely', I'm very rusty on my Javascript, not having done much web programming the past few years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

Sorry that made me realize that the problem was reading the files you've selected instead of just getting the code to work.

I've just added:

```
var files = $(this)[0].files;
```

To get the files collection the user selected (it could be one or more);

and then:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        alert(files[i].name);
    }
```

loop through all the files selected and just get the name of it. You can also read `.size` if you need to.

---

This will the proper way to handle what you are trying to achieve.

```js
$(document)
    .ready(function () {
        //element variables for the thumbnail display
        var dropbox = $("#dropbox"),
            filePropertyDisplay = $("#loadingImageFileProperties"),
            fileName = $("#dd_filename"),
            fileSize = $("#dd_filesize"),
            fileType = $("#dd_filetype"),
            gallery = $("#imageGallery"),
            uploading = $("#imageUploading"),
            fileSelect = document.getElementById("fileSelect"), //$("#fileSelect"),
            fileElem = document.getElementById("fileElem"), //$("#fileElem"),
            messages = $("#messageArea");

        gallery.hide();
        uploading.hide();

        //add event listeners to handle events
        dropbox.on("dragenter", function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        dropbox.on("dragover", function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        dropbox.on("drop", function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();

            var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
            var files = dt.files;

            handleFiles(files);
        });

        fileSelect.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            if (fileElem) {
                fileElem.click();
            }
            e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigation to "#"
        }, false);
        
        $('#fileElem').on('change',function(e){
            var files = $(this)[0].files;
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                alert(files[i].name);
                //alert(files[i].size);
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imageSelection" class="form-group">
      
      <label for="fileElem" class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-success", style="width:144px;"  id="fileSelect">Select images/videos</label>
      <input type="file" id = "fileElem" class = "col-md-10 form-control"
       style="display:none;"
       multiple = "multiple"
       accept = "image/*"
</div>
```

Comment: @ProgrammerV5...that should work, but doesn't...files is undefined this way.

Comment: You are right, the problem was somewhere else, just fixed the code. Sorry about that.